# Laptop mousepad buttons (right and left) stop working after installing Ubuntu (18.04)?

Tags: 18.04

After installing Ubuntu (18.04) for some days the buttons of my laptop mousepad works properly, but after some time both right and left button of mousepad stop working.

I am using Dell Latitude laptop, with specs as i5-5th gen processor, 8 GB RAM, 500 GB Hard disk.

I look online for the solution (even on ask Ubuntu forum, look for some commands, use GNOME tweaks also) but nothing works, there is no default in a laptop because the buttons work properly on Windows before installing Ubuntu.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried Settings > Mouse and Touchpad and Test Your Settings? Please [edit] your question with information after reading [ask]

Comment: Yes, I check that too but still no response from the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

From BIOS, open the following:

`System Properties > Keyboard/Mouse Features > Device Options`

From there, find the Internal Pointing Device or Touchpad and check if it is enabled.